# How to consume an API from the WSO2 API Cloud by Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, api, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hello I'm trying to consume an API from the WSO2 API Cloud in the Xamarin.Android, I created a button and I want the button to send an ID and receive some data. I'm new at programming so I would like to know which command should I use to use that API in my mobile. Thanks

```
       SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
       btnConsumer = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnConsumer);
       edtcpf = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edtcpf);
       txtcpf = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtcpf);

        btnConsumer.Click += BtnConsumer_Click;
    }

    private void BtnConsumer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.GET);
        request.AddParameter("name", "value"); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
        request.AddUrlSegment("id", "123"); // replaces matching token in request.Resource

        string url = "https://qa.api-latam.whirlpool.com/v1.0/consumer/54493746238" + edtcpf.Text;
        RestSharp.RestRequest call = new RestRequest(url);
        IRestResponse response = call.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;
```

Comment: show what you have tried.

Comment: please edit you question and add it there , not in comment section